# Why am I getting 'file not found' when trying to run CEWE Fotobuch / Kruidvat fotoservice on my 64 bit system?

Tags: 64-bit, dependencies, 32-bit, libraries, shared-library

When I install the [CEWE Fotobuch](http://www.cewe-fotobuch.de/download/get/linux/) (rebranded as "[Kruidvat fotoservice](http://www.kruidvat.nl/fotoservice/download.html)" in the Netherlands) software on my 64 bit system, the application does not start. Instead, I'm getting a `'file not found'` error. But the files are there! What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at Gilles' answer to this question for the background on this issue: ["No such file" when running a 32-bit program on a 64-bit system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231479/no-such-file-when-running-a-32-bit-program-on-a-64-bit-system)

The fastest solution is this:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch
```

I have informed CEWE about this issue and hopefully they will improve their installation script in the future so the user is notified beforehand when these libraries are missing.