# How to find why 64 bit application can run on 14.04 but not 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a 64 bits application (lmutil from Xilix Vivado tool). Which can run on 14.04, there's not problem. But when I run it on 12.04, I got the error:

```
bash: ./lmutil: No such file or directory
```

Is it there any way to find out the root cause for that?

Additional Information (Ubuntu 12.04):

```
$ file ./lmutil
./lmutil: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped

$ ldd ./lmutil
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa25fe000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fcb25bb0000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fcb258b4000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fcb2569d000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcb252df000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fcb250db000)
/lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fcb25de7000)
```

Comment: are you sure its installed and are you in the right directory?

Comment: I agree with @ElefantPhace. Are you _sure_ `./lmutil` is the correct location? `./` means `current-directory/`.

Comment: You can see the addition information I put it there. `file` and `ldd` command can pick it up. And 100% sure the file is there.

Comment: You question wasn't very clear.  You should've stated that you were running those on the 12.04 machine. Either way, obviously the file is not there if you can't run it. Add the ouput of `ls -la | grep lmutil` of your directory @EnzoChi

Comment: @ElefantPhace, sorry about that. There's the result from 12.04.

Comment: And what exactly is the output of `ls -lh lmutil`?

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 enzoc enzoc 1.5M Jun 27 08:38 lmutil`

Comment: it's likely that something it requires that's available on 14.04 isn't available on 12.04 - can you run `apt-get lsb install` and try running it again?  You can see the same issue discussed here with pointer to "official" description of the problem with lack of LSB support: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7490864.html and https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/flexlm-license-manager-20-may-fail-when-lsb-3-is-not-met

Comment: If you are not scared of low-level log files you could try command `strace -f -o trace.txt -v -s 1024 bash ./lmutil` (it will fail) but then look at file trace.txt. It will have the error but it will be burried among a large amount of log messages.

Comment: Thanks @AsyaKamsky, install `lsb` solve the problem. That application can run on 12.04 now.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky looks like a good answer..can you post that as the answer (and let me know with `@Ron` so that I can give you an upvote ;))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that something this program requires that's available on 14.04 isn't available on 12.04.

Most likely, that "something" is LSB compliance ([Linux Standard Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base)) - first thing to try is running `apt-get install lsb` and seeing if that resolves things.

This problem is discussed a few places with definitive word likely to be here:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/flexlm-license-manager-20-may-fail-when-lsb-3-is-not-met

They describe a workaround that involves creating the appropriate linker/loader, whether by installing or by symlinking an equivalent existing shared library.