# How to perform Qt installation

Tags: 14.04, qt, qt-creator, qt5

I downloaded *qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run*  but how to install it on ubuntu 14.04LTS?

This is the output which I get:

```
administrator@pc-7:~$ cd /home/administrator/Downloads/FlareGet/Applications
administrator@pc-7:~/Downloads/FlareGet/Applications$ chmod +x qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run 
administrator@pc-7:~/Downloads/FlareGet/Applications$ ./qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run
bash: ./qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run: No such file or directory

administrator@pc-7:~/Downloads/FlareGet/Applications$ whoami
administrator


administrator@pc-7:~/Downloads/FlareGet/Applications$ find ~ -type f -name "qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run"
find: `/home/administrator/.gnupg': Permission denied
find: `/home/administrator/.dbus': Permission denied
/home/administrator/Downloads/FlareGet/Applications/qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run
find: `/home/administrator/.cache/dconf': Permission denied
/home/administrator/Desktop/qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run
find: `/home/administrator/.gvfs': Permission denied
```

@A.B.

```
administrator@pc-7:~/Downloads/FlareGet/Applications$ chmod +x ~/Downloads/FlareGet/Applications/qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run 
administrator@pc-7:~/Downloads/FlareGet/Applications$ ~/Downloads/FlareGet/Applications/qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run
bash: /home/administrator/Downloads/FlareGet/Applications/qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run: No such file or directory
```

@A.B.

This is another thing which I tried:

```
administrator@pc-7:~/Downloads/FlareGet/Applications$ chmod +x qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run
administrator@pc-7:~/Downloads/FlareGet/Applications$ . qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run
bash: .: qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run: cannot execute binary file
```

Comment: this is offline installation i am talking about.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `ls -la --escape ~/Desktop`

Comment: total 1047540
drwxr-xr-x  4 administrator administrator      4096 Sep  1 11:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 43 administrator administrator      4096 Sep  1 13:58 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 administrator administrator    508886 Jul 22 13:00 17870614_14J.pdf
-rw-rw-r--  1 administrator administrator    452282 Aug 13 14:01 bigmb.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 administrator administrator      4268 Jun  1 11:53 installing\ java\ commands.docx
-rw-rw-r--  1 administrator administrator     56068 May 21 14:01 Intro\ page.odt
-rwxrwxr-x  1 administrator administrator 572293599 Aug 31 16:31 qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run

Comment: And my question is when I apply the commands you first told to install qt, this error comes:     bash: ./qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run: No such file or directory

Comment: And add the output of `whoami`

Comment: Ok, next one `find ~ -type f -name "qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run"`. Add the output of the command into your question and give me a ping with @A.B.

Comment: What's the output of `uname -a`

Comment: The command `. qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run` can't work. Use `~/Downloads/FlareGet/Applications` and after that `./qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run` Note the slash between `.` and the filename

Comment: And a last try: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the file `qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run` executable

```
chmod +x ~/Downloads/FlareGet/Applications/qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run
```

Run with

```
~/Downloads/FlareGet/Applications/qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run
```

And you will see this

[image]

Comment: administrator@pc-7:~$ cd /home/administrator/Desktop
administrator@pc-7:~/Desktop$ chmod +x qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run
administrator@pc-7:~/Desktop$ ./qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run
bash: ./qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run: No such file or directory
administrator@pc-7:~/Desktop$

Comment: Please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: it is there on desktop but still not working.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -la ~/Desktop`?

Comment: this is the output

Comment: `qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run t.` is the `t.` at the end a typo?

Comment: qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run

Comment: Sir, same situation :( @A.B.

Comment: What should I do sir?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of comments. The `*.run` you are trying to  download has `x86` in the file name, meaning it is for 32-bit OS, so that is one thing to keep track of. If your OS is 64-bit, you may need to install libc6:i386 . More on that [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/231500/295286)

Second, in my tests running the file requires full path to the file, not just `./qt*.run`. I cannot explain why it does it that way, but it just does.

Bellow is a small script I wrote that determines correct OS version, downloads appropriate version of QT, and installs it from `$HOME/QT` folder. Perhaps a little verbose, but it should ease the manual labor.

```
#!/bin/bash
# set -x

printf "Qt INSTALLER SCRIPT STARTED\n"
ARCH=$(uname -m)
printf "Your OS is %s \n" $ARCH 

if [ $ARCH = "x86_64" ];then
  FILE="qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.4.1.run"
else 
  FILE="qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run"
fi

cd $HOME

if [ ! -e QT ];then
  printf "CREATING $HOME/QT folder\n" 
  mkdir $HOME/QT
fi

cd $HOME/QT

if [ ! -e $FILE  ];then
    printf "DOWNLOADING BINARY  to %s\n" $(pwd)
    wget http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.4/5.4.1/$FILE
fi

echo $PWD
chmod 755 $FILE
$( readlink -f $FILE )
```

Comment: I've tested the installation of the x86 on my 64-bit system too. In my case, that makes no difference.

Comment: The message in the question `bash: .: qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run: cannot execute binary file`, OP starts the bin with `. Foo` and not with `./Foo`

Comment: @Sajjadmanal Glad you have it figured out. May I ask how did you solve your issue ? Was my answer helpful in any way ?

Comment: My PC was X86-64 and I had installed qt for x86 i.e, 32 bit