# Ubuntu not finding file (permission 755)

Tags: bash, executable

Running ubuntu 15.10 64 bit. Extracted oracle's jdk and was trying to run java. Permission look ok, but why is it not finding java executable -

```
raj@raj-VirtualBox:~/jdk1.8.0_74/bin$ ./java -version
bash: ./java: No such file or directory
raj@raj-VirtualBox:~/jdk1.8.0_74/bin$ ls -l | grep java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 raj raj   5730 Jan 29 22:08 java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 raj raj   5881 Jan 29 22:08 javac
-rwxr-xr-x 1 raj raj   5889 Jan 29 22:08 javadoc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 raj raj   2293 Dec 22 15:58 javafxpackager
-rwxr-xr-x 1 raj raj   5881 Jan 29 22:08 javah
-rwxr-xr-x 1 raj raj   5881 Jan 29 22:08 javap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 raj raj   2293 Dec 22 15:58 javapackager
-rwxr-xr-x 1 raj raj   1809 Jan 29 22:08 java-rmi.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 raj raj 104523 Jan 29 22:08 javaws
raj@raj-VirtualBox:~/jdk1.8.0_74/bin$ java -version
bash: /home/raj/jdk1.8.0_74/bin/java: No such file or directory
raj@raj-VirtualBox:~/jdk1.8.0_74/bin$ javac
bash: /home/raj/jdk1.8.0_74/bin/javac: No such file or directory
raj@raj-VirtualBox:~/jdk1.8.0_74/bin$ pwd
/home/raj/jdk1.8.0_74/bin
raj@raj-VirtualBox:~/jdk1.8.0_74/bin$ cp java java2
raj@raj-VirtualBox:~/jdk1.8.0_74/bin$ ./java2
bash: ./java2: No such file or directory
raj@raj-VirtualBox:~/jdk1.8.0_74/bin$ java2
bash: /home/raj/jdk1.8.0_74/bin/java2: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Seems a lot like http://askubuntu.com/questions/231479/no-such-file-when-running-a-32-bit-program-on-a-64-bit-system?rq=1 , are you using 32 bit java on a 64 bit system?

Comment: Yes. It was the 32 bit jdk that I downloaded. 64 bit works just fine.  Thanks for pointing that out