# chroot into 32bit system from 64bit machine

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, chroot

when I try to chroot into my 32bit system from a 64bit machine, it is responding with `/bin/bash is not found` despite the fact that the file existed in the specified directory. is there any way to get around with this problem?
thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No such file" when running a 32-bit program on a 64-bit system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/231479/no-such-file-when-running-a-32-bit-program-on-a-64-bit-system)

Comment: The title of the question does not match the question (from/into).